# Using run time parameters with BigtableIO in Apache Beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to use run time parameters with BigtableIO in Apache Beam to write to BigTable.

I have created a pipeline to read from BigQuery and writing to Bigtable. 
The pipeline works fine when i provide static parameters (using ConfigBigtableIO and ConfigBigtableConfiguration, referring to example here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/dataflow-connector-examples/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/bigtable/dataflow/example/HelloWorldWrite.java) but I am getting a compile error while trying to setup the pipeline with run time parameters. 
The options is setup with all parameters being runtime Value Providers.

```
    p.apply(BigQueryIO.readTableRows().fromQuery(options.getBqQuery())
            .usingStandardSql())
            .apply(ParDo.of(new TransFormFn(options.getColumnFamily(), options.getRowKey(), options.getColumnKey(), options.getRowKeySuffix())))

            .apply(BigtableIO.write().withProjectId(options.getBigtableProjectId()).
                    withInstanceId(options.getBigtableInstanceId()).
                   withTableId(options.getBigtableTableId()));
```

It is expecting the output of Bigtable.write()... to be  org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform,OutputT>
while Bigtable.write() is returning a Write object. 
Can you help with providing the correct syntax to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Here's the definition of the Write class: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.4.0/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.java#L467:  public abstract static class Write
      extends PTransform<PCollection<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>>, PDone>

Answer (score 2):

Runtime parameters are meant to be used in Dataflow templates.

Are you trying to create a template and run the pipeline using the template? If yes, you would need following steps:

1. Create an Options that has runtime parameters you need, i.e.
   ValueProvider tableId.
2. Pass these runtime parameters to the config object: i.e. withTableId(ValueProvider tableId) =>
   withTableId(options.getTableId())
3. Construct your template
4. Execute your pipeline using the template.

The advantage of using a template is that it allows pipeline to be constructed once and executed multiple times later with runtime parameters.
For more information on how to use Dataflow template: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview

When not using Dataflow template, you don't have set runtime parameters, i.e. withTableId(ValueProvider tableId). Instead, use withTableId(String tableId).

Hope this helps!